# AI suggestions button in ask/edit question interface gives 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, 404-not-found, ask-question-form, formatting-assistant

I have just finished writing a question, and I noticed at the bottom of the screen a new "AI suggested edits for your question" section, with a "Get suggestions" button.

[image: Get suggestions button]

This button appears to only be enabled once the body of the question reaches a certain length.

When I clicked it, I got an exception in a popup:

[image: Error retrieving content formatting update: 404]

> Error retrieving content formatting update: 404

Comment: I missed the memo. when was the re-release of the formatting assistant announced?

Comment: @starball I saw it show up yesterday ... I also did not see an announcement other than the "Google coop" one.

Comment: the button is disabled for me. but if I manually invoke the callback that's bound to it on the `click` event, the request it makes (to `/ai/content-formatting`) returns with status 404 like you described.

Comment: Maybe the button was meant to be hidden from the public and was only supposed to be in test builds, but accidentally made its way to production.

Comment: @starball It hasn't - mods have not been informed in backchannels either

Comment: Next Step: AI write questions without user input ...

Comment: @starball it appears to only enable once the body of the message reaches a certain length

Comment: An AI feature is broken? [meta-tag:status-working-as-I-expected]

Comment: There are 2 ways to play this (definitely not biased in any way): --> **Remove the feature** <--, or *fix the feature*

Comment: @Fastnlight - Shouldn't give the option of fixing it. They should just remove it.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTyQe.png

Comment: It initially didn't appear for me on my main account, only on a sock. I'm still not sure why, but it has appeared on my main account after  rev 2024.3.7.5898. I think this is a good sign that they're actually re-rolling the feature without informing us. The endpoint is still dead at least. Staff has unfortunately not responded yet, so this is still speculation.

Comment: the length requirement is probably to "fix" the previously reported issues of just typing a few characters and then a question being materialized out of nothing basically. Ex. [this](/a/425167/11107541)

Comment: As of at least rev 2024.3.8.5948, there's a new data field in the page HTML. The button re-disappeared on my main account but is still there on my sock. The difference is in the second field of said data: `{"isUserNewAsker":false,"isContentFormattingExperimentNewVariant":true,"minimalBodyLengthForContentFormatting":150}`. The name of this field is likely as close as we'll get to a confirmation of the experiment returning before, presumably, SE rolls it out without any advance notice. I also pinged 3 staff members yesterday and linked to this question, and I have not gotten a reply

Comment: *"[Did you see the memo about this?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsLUidiYm0w)"*

Comment: "[Do not press this button](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0XS20Rqz9Js&t=37s)"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT**: A fix has been deployed. Please let us know if you're still seeing this.

Sorry for the false alarm here folks - fix is incoming.  We initially ran the content formatter as an experiment.  It has been turned off for a long time, but we never did the follow up clean up task to remove the experiment branching logic.  When we run experiments in our architecture, they sometimes re-use the old cookie keys.  Whenever we turn on a new experiment, we try to double check against existing experiments and make sure we're not re-using an active key, but missed the check here.  We'll retro to see if we can find a better solution to this so it's not on the devs to remember to double check every time.

The endpoint itself is turned off so all the calls to `/ai/content-formatter` just 404'd back.

**TLDR**; new experiment elsewhere on the site re-activated content formatter by accident.  Good reminder to finally clean up that code, which should be pushing to prod soon.

Comment: why not just use a UUID for the experiment key, or append one to a human-readable name and use that as the key? or append the date the experiment starts on?

Comment: @starball, it's a great question, but the answer is a complex amalgam of lots of architectural decisions to arrive at where we are today too long for a comment and probably out of scope for a big ol' meta deep dive.  But it's a reasonable idea and incidents like this give us more data / incentive to improve or overhaul our existing experimenting systems.